# Парсинг JSON в RxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Дело в том, что я раньше парсил локальный `JSON` в `AsyncTask`. Но я начал изучать `RxJava` и пытаюсь распарсить огромный `JSON` файл из `assets` таким образом:

```
Observable.just(AssetsUtil.getCountryList(context))
                .flatMapIterable(new Function<List<Country>, Iterable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<?> apply(List<Country> countryList) throws Exception {
                        return countryList;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(item -> mView.onCountryListReceive((Country) item));
```

где `onCountryListReceive((Country) item))`:

```
@Override
public void onCountryListReceive(Country country) {
    countries.add(country);
    PreferencesUtil.putCountryList(getActivity(), countries);
}
```

`AssetsUtil.getCountryList(context)`:

```
public static List<Country> getCountryList(Context context) {
    String countryJson = loadJSONFromAsset(context);

    List<Country> countryList = new Gson().fromJson(countryJson, new TypeToken<List<Country>>(){}.getType());

    cityList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (countryList != null) {
        for (Country country : countryList){
            cityList.addAll(country.getCities());
        }
    }

    return countryList;
}
```

Я уверен, что делаю не правильно, так как, `MainThread` зависает при парсинге.

Вопрос: Как реализовать задачи такого рода в `RxJava`, может есть методы типа `doInBackground`, блок, внутри которого можно решать тяжелые задачи?

Comment: Попробуйте just на defer заменить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Заменил, ошибка выходит

Comment: А если fromCallable?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Благодарю, помогло. Хотелось бы узнать еще, как люди решают задачи такого рода...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, `Observable.just()` выполнится в том потоке, где вызывается. Т.е. на него `subscribeOn()` не подействует.

А вот если `just` заменить на `fromCallable`, то код внутри будет вызван в том потоке, коий в `subscribeOn()` указан.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
AndroidShedulers.mainThread
```

Попробуйте

```
new Thread()
```

Или

```
Shedulers.newThread()
```

Если внутри вам нужно работать с UI то делайте так

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //работайте с UI
    }
});
```

Comment: Я думаю не получится, так как помимо `PreferencesUtil.putCountryList(getActivity(), countries);` у меня там будет работа с `progressDialog();`